# Django 404 error ('Page not found') after runserver

Tags: python, django

My project is named 'pages', and when I runserver I get this error. Anybody have any clue how to fix this error.

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Using the
>   URLconf defined in pages_project.urls, Django tried these URL
>   patterns, in this order: admin/ The empty path didn't match any of
>   these. You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your
>   Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a
>   standard 404 page.

My settings.py file looks like this:

```
"""
Django settings for pages_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.0.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*u)%-zmf=2g-c*3z2-&=n=asty5v36n62^90_u*-#83!wb=)eq'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'pages', # new
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pages_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pages_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

And my urls.py in my 'pages' folder is

```
from django.urls import path


from . import views


urlpatterns = [

    path(' ', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),

]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that the main urls.py only includes the admin pattern. You also need to include the pages urls.

Also, you have a space in your path pattern. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a *space* in your path; `' '`. This would mean that the url is  http://127.0.0.1:8000/%20. Delete the space.

```
path('', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home')
```

Answer (score 0):

You project urls: Remove the space

*pages/urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$', views.HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
]
```

Add your app urls at your project urls so that way your project can see your app url

*projectName/urls.py*

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [     
    ...  
    url(r'^', include('pages.urls')),      
]
```